# Py4JJavaError when initialises a spark session in anaconda pycharm enviroment

Tags: java, windows, pyspark, pycharm

java was installed in my anaconda enivorment by conda install -c cyclus java-jdk,
I am on windows.

pyspark-2.4.4
Python version = 3.10.4
java version = [image: Java]

when i initilise a spark session I get the following error.

```
findspark.init()

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("CustomerChurn") \
    .master("local") \
    .config() \
    .getOrCreate()


Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o16.set.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have not seen this error online, does anyone know what is the issue

EDIT: issue resolved, I added a comment beneath

Comment: EDIT: Successfully installed py4j-0.10.9 i was using version 0.10.9 which caused the error, installed 3.3.0 spark too which fixed errors. Hopefully it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it installing java version 1.8. (The version  of py4j was 0.10.9 and the version of spark was 3.2.1).